# Adding an extra config property to a grail target

Tags: grails, jenkins

In my config.groovy my dev environment is...

```
development {
    ... 
    grails.resources.mappers.yuicssminify.disable = true
    grails.resources.mappers.yuijsminify.disable = true
    grails.resources.mappers.hashandcache.disable = true
    grails.resources.mappers.zip.disable = true

}
```

When I run `grails dev war` from jenkins I want an extra property in some cases.  This property is:

```
grails.plugin.jbossas.removeLog4jJars = false
```

I cannot alter the development environment in the `Config.groovy`. Is there any way I can pass in this extra property?

Comment: Why not add a new environment with that config?

Comment: @dolleri I will do that in future but can't right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution would be a new environment for your jenkins:

```
jenkins {
    grails.plugin.jbossas.removeLog4jJars = false    
}
```

If this is not an option (like mentioned in the comments) it is also possible to move this configuration value into a system specific property file:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:/home/user/my-config.properties"]
```

Within `my-config.properties` on the jenkins system you can do:

```
grails.plugin.jbossas.removeLog4jJars = false
```

The `my-config.properties` files of other systems stay empty (I think they don't even need to exist).

If this is also not an option you can do something (not so nice) like this:

```
development {
  if (MyUtils.isJenkins()) {
    grails.plugin.jbossas.removeLog4jJars = false
  }
  ...
}
```

Within `MyUtils.isJenkins()` you have to determine on which system your application is running. For example:

```
class MyUtils {

  public static boolean isJenkins() {
    def env = System.getenv()
    return env[IS_JENKINS]        
  }
}
```

This example checks if the system variable `IS_JENKINS` is set (you can add other ways to determine on which system you are running like)